# React Router: Excluding a route from root path

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently setting up basic authentication for my React app. I have an `AppWithAuth` class which wraps the normal App, and a Login page. My goal is to redirect to `/login` when a user is not authenticated, but allow them to visit any other route if they are, such as `/` (dashboard path), `/users`, etc.

The problem I have is that the app wishes to render the root directory, but will redirect to the Login if not Authenticated. But **since the login route is included in the root directory render, the app endlessly redirects.** Any way to achieve the desired effect? Here's the gist of my code:

App:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router> {/* The main routes of the app, e.g. /users... */}
        ...
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

AppWithAuth:

```
class AppWithAuth extends React.Component {
  isAuthenticated = () => {
    // suppose this returns true if user is authenticated, false otherwise
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/' render={props => {
          return this.isAuthenticated ? (
            <App />
          ) : (
            <Redirect to='/login' />
          )
        }} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Switch` then you can match paths exclusively. In that case order matters - the first path to match will break the switch, just like the `switch` statement. You can also leverage `exact` attribute to match a path exactly if you need to. For example:

```
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route
                            path="/"
                            render={props => {
                                return this.isAuthenticated ? (
                                    <App />
                                ) : (
                                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        <Route path="/home" component={App} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about try to this?

1. make `ProtectedRoute` for authenticated users

```
export default ({ isAuthenticated, component: C, ...rest }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    <Route {...rest} render={props => <C {...props} />} />
  } else {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />
  }
}
```

2. use Router, Route in App.js

```
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute'
class App extends React.Component {
  isAuthenticated = () => {
    // suppose this returns true if user is authenticated, false otherwise
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='login' component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute path='/' component={Main} isAuthenticated={this.isAuthenticated()} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

The `ProtectedRoute` is only accept for authenticated users any others redirect to /login